# Libgdx Music error QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present

Tags: java, libgdx, sound, music

**Problem solved with music = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("song.mp3"));**

I am looking for music implementation in my app with LibGDX. I saw the guide provided in LibGDX documentation but it doesn't work for me and this is my code :

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

    Music music;
    public GameScreen(MyGdxGame game)   {

        music = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.local("assets/song.mp3"));
        music.play();

    }
```

When I run my code it returns me this error :

```
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidAudio.newMusic(AndroidAudio.java:124)
            at GameScreen.<init>(GameScreen.java:62)
            at FirstScreen.render(FirstScreen.java:99)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:422)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1522)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
05-22 20:49:06.213  15534-15534/  E/SysUtils﹕ ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
05-22 20:49:09.358  15534-15572/ E/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
05-22 20:49:09.374  15534-15572/ E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 10072

com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error loading audio file: assets/song.mp3
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidAudio.newMusic(AndroidAudio.java:132)
            at .GameScreen.<init>(GameScreen.java:62)
            at .game.FirstScreen.render(FirstScreen.java:99)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:422)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1522)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1076)
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1022)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidAudio.newMusic(AndroidAudio.java:124)
            at .game.GameScreen.<init>(GameScreen.java:62)
            at .game.FirstScreen.render(FirstScreen.java:99)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:422)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1522)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
```

Comment: Is the GameScreen being instantiated in your ApplicationAdapter's `create()` method? If you're not sure what I mean, please post the method in which you instantiate the GameScreen.

Comment: @StrongJoshua Yes it is instantiated in my create method but I extend Game and not ApplicationAdapter

Comment: Hm I don't know, this might be better asked in the [LibGdx forums](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/).